# How to get the current instance module in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

That title doesn't really explain everything so here goes.  I have two Rails engines that share some functionality (ie. user model and authentication).  I have a base `User` class and then two other User classes that inherit from this base class for each app like so:

```
class User; end
class App1::User < ::User; end
class App2::User < ::User; end
```

My authentication has a method similar to the following

```
def user_from_session
  User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
end
```

which is included in my application_controller.  My problem here is that when a user is fetched... it always uses the base `User` class.  What I really want is to be able to fetch a User that is the same type as the app calling that method.

For instance, if a user is on `SomeController`:

```
class App1::SomeController < ApplicationController; end
```

I want the method in the application_controller to pull out the `App1` so that it instantiates an `App1::User` rather than just a `User`

Is this possible?

I'm NOT looking for a solution that involves two `user_from_session` methods, one for each application.  I am aware of how to implement that.  I'm more interested in know if this type of thing is possible in Ruby.

Comment: Where do you call `user_from_session` method from?

Comment: ah sorry, it's called from a before_filter in application_controller...  it's actually called from my `current_user` method inside there

Answer (score 0):

Though I'd caution you to find a better, less hacky way to do this, here's how you might do it:

```
def user_from_session
  # App1::Whatever::FooController -> App1::Whatever
  module_name = self.class.name.split('::')[0..-2].join('::')
  # App1::Whatever -> App1::Whatever::User
  user_class = "#{module_name}::User".constantize
  # App1::Whatever::User.find_by_id(...)
  user_class.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
end
```

Comment: I never ended up testing this out.  I decided to re-organize my controllers so that each app has its own application_controller that it inherits from that defines the user_from_session method.  Had I tested this however I'd mark it correct assuming it worked...